# Bootstrap Modal not closing on ajax success

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

One of my razor pages is using bootstrap modal for Add/Edit/Delete operations.What happens now is on ajax success,its not closing the modal and added content is not showing.I cannot use location.reload function since it wont focus on the current tab.Here is my code.

StaffAssets.cshtml

```
@page
@model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.StaffAssetsModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<br />

<!-- CREATE NEW ASSET BUTTON-->
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalStaffAssets">
        Add New Asset
    </button>
</div>
<br />

<!-- CREATE NEW ASSET MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalStaffAssets" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Add New Asset</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form asp-page-handler="AddAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffAddAssetsCompleted">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["StaffID"]' />
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["EmpID"]' />
                    <!-- Asset Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Date-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Asset Size -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" name="StaffAssets.Size" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetSize" class="form-control-staff">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Return Qty-->
                    @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                            <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                            <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                        </div>*@

                    <!-- Return Date-->
                    @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                            <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                            <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                        </div>*@
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- STAFF ASSETS LIST-->
@if (Model.ShowStaffAssets != null)
{
    <table class="table" border="1" style="width:750px;margin-left:175px;">
        <thead style="background-color:silver">
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].StaffAssetName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].IssuedQty)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowStaffAssets[0].IssuedDate)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ShowStaffAssets)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffAssetName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssuedQty)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IssuedDate)</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/images/pencil(1).png" alt="Edit">&nbsp;<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit_@item.StaffAssetName">Edit</a> |
                        <img src="~/images/icons8-delete-trash-16.png" alt="Delete">&nbsp;<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete_@item.StaffAssetName">Delete</a>

                        <!--EDIT STAFF ASSET-->
                        <div id="myModalEdit_@item.StaffAssetName" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Edit Asset</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form asp-page-handler="EditAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffEditAssetsCompleted">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@item.StaffID' />
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@item.EmpID' />

                                            <!-- Asset Name -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                @*<input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" value="@item.StaffAssetName" class="form-control-staff" />*@
                                                <select asp-for="@item.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="@item.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Issued Date-->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="@item.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="datepicker" type="text" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Asset Size -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                @*<input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" value="@item.StaffAssetName" class="form-control-staff" />*@
                                                <select asp-for="@item.Size" name="StaffAssets.Size" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetSize" class="form-control-staff">
                                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Return Qty-->
                                            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" value="NULL" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- Return Date-->
                                            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                                                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                                                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="datepicker" type="text" /><br />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!---DELETE STAFF ASSET-->
                        <div id="myModalDelete_@item.StaffAssetName" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Delete Asset</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form asp-page-handler="DeleteAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffDeleteAssetsCompleted">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@item.StaffID' />
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@item.EmpID' />
                                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" type="hidden" value='@item.StaffAssetName' />
                                            <p class="text-center">Are you sure want to delete this @item.StaffAssetName?</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

The Ajax functions

```
function staffAddAssetsCompleted(event) {
            if (event.responseText != "") {
                $("#Assets").html(event.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Assets Has Been Added Successfully");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffAssets",
                    type: "get",
                    success: function (result) {                        
                        $("#Assets").html(result);
                        $('a[href="#Assets"]').tab('show');
                    }
                })
               
            }
        }

function staffEditAssetsCompleted(event) {
            if (event.responseText != "") {
                $("#Assets").html(event.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Assets Has Been Added Successfully");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffAssets",
                    type: "get",
                    success: function (result) {                        
                        $("#Assets").html(result);
                        $('a[href="#Assets"]').tab('show');
                    }
                })
                
            }
        }
```

After submitting the form,the screen will be like this

[image]

Its not displaying the added asset in the page.Anyhelp would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What is `$("#Assets")`?I cannot find it in your code.

Comment: @YiYi You, that is the tab content id, which is defined in Details razor page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Change

```
<form asp-page-handler="AddAssetsDetails" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="staffAddAssetsCompleted">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["StaffID"]' />
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["EmpID"]' />
                    <!-- Asset Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Issued Date-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Asset Size -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                        <select asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" name="StaffAssets.Size" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetSize" class="form-control-staff">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        </select>
                        <br />
                        <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Return Qty-->
                    @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                            <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                            <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                        </div>*@

                    <!-- Return Date-->
                    @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                            <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                            <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                            <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                        </div>*@
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

to

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["StaffID"]' />
                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.EmpID" type="hidden" value='@TempData["EmpID"]' />
                <!-- Asset Name -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                    <select asp-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" name="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetName" class="form-control-staff">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.StaffAssetName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                </div>

                <!-- Issued Quantity -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" name="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                </div>

                <!-- Issued Date-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                    <input asp-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" name="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.IssuedDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                </div>

                <!-- Asset Size -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                    <select asp-for="StaffAssets.Size" name="StaffAssets.Size" asp-items="Model.ShowAssetSize" class="form-control-staff">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.Size" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
                </div>

                <!-- Return Qty-->
                @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnQty" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>*@

                <!-- Return Date-->
                @*<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffAssets.ReturnDate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>*@
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" onclick="submit1()"/>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Add the following code to the razor page with tabs:

```
function submit1() {
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffAssets?handler=AddAssetsDetails",
                data: $("#form1").serialize(),
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
                    $("#Assets").html(data);
                }
            });

        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: ,Thanks for the response,I just added $(".modal-backdrop").remove(); Everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

**Well you can try this**

```
$('#modalStaffAssets').modal('toggle');
$('#modalStaffAssets').modal('show');
$('#modalStaffAssets').modal('hide')
```

Each line has it own effect.